regroup tupples in different group with kmeans method using only a number in position 0
liste = [ (1, ["A",1,"C"]) , (3, ["A",1,"C"]) , (1000.256, ["B",1,"C"]) , (1002, ["C",1,"C"]) , (5, ["D",1,"C"]) , (999.3, ["E",1,"C"]) , (2.5, ["F",1,"C"])]

xxx=np.array(liste,dtype=object)

best_n_clusters,best_silhouette_score=None,-1
range_n_clusters=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

for n_clusters in range_n_clusters:
    clusterer=KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
    cluster_labels=clusterer.fit(xxx)
    silhouette_avg=silhouette_score(xxx,cluster_labels)
    if silhouette_avg>best_silhouette_score:
        best_silhouettescore=silhouette_avg
        best_n_clusters=n_clusters

kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=best_n_clusters)
cluster_labels=kmeans.fit(xxx)

for r in range(best_n_clusters):
    group=xxx[cluster_labels==i]
    print(f"Groupe {r+1} : {group}")

I have an initial list, composed of tuples. In the first position [0], it's a number, in position [1] a list of values. What I would like is to regroup the tuples in different groups, to join together the tuples which have a number in position [0] close enough.
Here in this example, I would like 2 lists in exit in a print:

[ (1, ["A",1,"C"]) , (3, ["A",1,"C"]) , (5, ["D",1,"C"]) , (2.5, ["F",1,"C"])]
[ (1000.256, ["B",1,"C"]) , (1002, ["C",1,"C"]) , (999.3, ["E",1,"C"])].

I would like to use the method of kmeans to group this point, I find this method quite efficient to do that, and determine the best number of groups with the method of the silhouette. I already used this methode to group points with coordinates, but here there is only a value, the number in position [0], to regroup them, and I get some issues to do that.
The problem I have is that the structure I give to do that "clusterer.fit(xxx)" returns an error : "setting an array element with a sequence".
How can I solve this problem ?

Solution :
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

# Your initial list of tuples
liste = [(1, ["A", 1, "C"]), (3, ["A", 1, "C"]), (1000.256, ["B", 1, "C"]),
     (1002, ["C", 1, "C"]), (5, ["D", 1, "C"]), (999.3, ["E", 1, "C"]),
     (2.5, ["F", 1, "C"])]

# Extract numeric values (position [0]) and reshape
numeric_values = np.array([t[0] for t in liste]).reshape(-1, 1)

# Determine optimal number of clusters using silhouette scores
best_n_clusters, best_silhouette_score = None, -1
range_n_clusters = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

for n_clusters in range_n_clusters:

    if n_clusters>=len(liste):pass
    else:
        clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
        cluster_labels = clusterer.fit_predict(numeric_values)
        silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(numeric_values, cluster_labels)
        if silhouette_avg > best_silhouette_score:
            best_silhouette_score = silhouette_avg
            best_n_clusters = n_clusters

# Perform K-means clustering with the optimal number of clusters
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=best_n_clusters)
cluster_labels = kmeans.fit_predict(numeric_values)

# Group tuples based on cluster labels
groups = [[] for _ in range(best_n_clusters)]
for i, t in enumerate(liste):
    groups[cluster_labels[i]].append(t)

# Print the grouped tuples
for r, group in enumerate(groups):
    print(f"Group {r + 1}: {group}")


please try to include some explanation in your post as well
